How to add functionalities to the icons in pyqt5?
I am using PyQt5 and python 3.12. I want to add functionalities to the icons in the toolbar.
I tried to search on internet but didn't find anything.
My code:
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(816, 702)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(39, 190, 255);")
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Image/—Pngtree—settings icon_4419959 (1).png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
        self.Settings_icon.setIcon(icon)
        self.Settings_icon.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 400))
        self.Settings_icon.setObjectName("Settings_icon")
        
        self.block_web_icon = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.block_web_icon.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 160, 261, 291))
        self.block_web_icon.setText("")


Icons don't have "functionalities", buttons do. Please clarify what you want to do, as right now your question is too vague. Also, that looks like a pyuic generated file: such files have a clear warning in their header comment about not editing them, as it's discouraged and considered bad practice. Please follow the official guidelines about using Designer. You should also avoid fixed geometries, and use layout managers instead (including with Designer).
